# Obtain matrices by switch a one and a zero-Local search

Tags: r

Let's start with the following matrix.

```
M <- matrix(c(0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,
          0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,
          0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
          0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,
          0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,
          0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1),nrow = 8,ncol = 6)


      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0    0    1
[4,]    1    0    0    1    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
[6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
[8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
```

I want to obtain set of matrices by switching ones and zeros. For each column, starting from column 1, I wanna obtain set of matrices by switching `1` in (4,1) with `0` in (1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (5,1), (6,1) and then do the same for `1`s in (7,1) and (8,1). Then continue to the other columns. There are altogether
90 matrices (15 for each column, 15*6) after switching. This is just an example. I have bigger size matrices. How do I generalize for other cases?

Comment: Double checking, do you want to swap the 1s and 0s in the 1st column (rows 1 - 6), then the same column for later rows, and then for each column individually? It seems like your end goal is to swap all the 1st and 0s simultaneously.

A quick way to swap all the 1s and 0s simultaneously is:
M <- abs(1 - M)

But that only works if you want to swap them all at once instead of one column at a time.

Comment: @MatthewBorg I wanna do for individual columns.

Comment: I'd just write a (nested) `for` loop... the logic seems pretty straightforward. `for(one in which(x == 1)) { for (zero in which(x == 0)) { ... }}`. Put that in a function that operates on a single column, then you can `apply` that function to each column.

Comment: @Gregor I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution. You could wrap the whole thing up into a function. It produces a list of lists of matrices, `results`, where `results[[i]]` is a list of matrices with the `i`th column switched.

```
    column_switcher = function(x) {
        ones = which(x == 1)
        zeros = which(x == 0)
        results = matrix(rep(x, length(ones) * length(zeros)), nrow = length(x))
        counter = 1
        for (one in ones) {
            for (zero in zeros) {
                results[one, counter] = 0
                results[zero, counter] = 1
                counter = counter + 1
            }
        }
        return(results)
    }

    switched = lapply(1:ncol(M), function(col) column_switcher(M[, col]))
    results = lapply(seq_along(switched), function(m_col) {
        lapply(1:ncol(switched[[m_col]]), function(i) {
            M[, m_col] = switched[[m_col]][, i]
            return(M)
            })
        })

    results[[1]]
    # [[1]]
    #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    # [1,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
    # [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
    # [3,]    0    1    0    0    0    1
    # [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    0
    # [5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
    # [6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
    # [7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
    # [8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
    # 
    # [[2]]
    #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
    # [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0
    # [2,]    1    0    0    0    0    0
    # [3,]    0    1    0    0    0    1
    # [4,]    0    0    0    1    1    0
    # [5,]    0    0    0    1    1    1
    # [6,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
    # [7,]    1    1    1    1    0    0
    # [8,]    1    0    1    0    0    1
    # 
    # ...
```

Checking the length of the list and the lengths of the sublists, they're all there.

```
    length(results)
    # [1] 6
    lengths(results)
    # [1] 15 15 15 15 15 15
```